# Combining formulas

Tags: excel, formula

I have this formula in a table which basically collects data from two columns and combines them. Now, I'm looking to combine this formula with a `REPLACE` formula that basically takes these characters `æ,ø,å` and replaces them with `a,o,a`.

Here's the formula:

```
=LOWER(LEFT(tableFaste[[#This Row];[Fornavn:]])&tableFaste[[#This Row];[Etternavn:]])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use SUBSTITUTE

```
=SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(LOWER(LEFT(tableFaste[[#This Row];[Fornavn:]])&tableFaste[[#This Row];[Etternavn:]]),"æ","a"),"ø","o"),"å","a")
```

Answer (score 2):

Sorry, don't know of a Formula way to remove any of a list of characters from a string. You might have to revert to vba for this. Here's a user defined function to do it. Your formula will become

```
=DeleteChars([@UserName],{"æ","ø","å";"a","o","a"})
```

To replace the characters use {"æ","ø","å";"a","o","a"} where the list up to the ; is the old characters, after the ; the new. You can make the list as long as you need, just make sure the lists are the same length.
To Delete the characters replace use {"æ","ø","å"} an array list of characters you want to remove

UDF code:

```
Function DeleteChars(r1 As Range, ParamArray c() As Variant) As Variant
    Dim i As Long
    Dim s As String

    s = r1
    If UBound(c(0), 1) = 1 Then
        For i = LBound(c(0), 2) To UBound(c(0), 2)
            s = Replace(s, c(0)(1, i), "")
        Next
    Else
        For i = LBound(c(0), 2) To UBound(c(0), 2)
            s = Replace(s, c(0)(1, i), c(0)(2, i))
        Next
    End If
    DeleteChars = s
End Function
```